# How to write a workable .vimrc for both vim & vi in Red Hat 6?

Tags: vim, configuration, vi

I've install both vi & vim in RedHat 6.7.
Both of them are 7.4 but with different features turn on or off.
I've setup a line in ~/.vimrc `set mouse=a`
And the color scheme molokai is imported by plugin manager `dein`.
These features are workable when I type `vim`, but it shows error message when I use `view` which is a link to `/bin/vi`.
The error messages are

```
Error detected while processing /home/myname/.vimrc:    
line   21:                                            
E538: No mouse support: mouse=a                       
line  263:                                            
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'molokai'
```

I'm wonder how could I write a workable .vimrc for both `vi/view` or `vim`?
Here is the features about mouse on the different versions:

```
$ /bin/vi --version|grep mouse
+acl             -farsi           -mouse_sgr       -tag_old_static
-arabic          -file_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-autocmd         -find_in_path    -mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    -float           -mouse_xterm     +terminfo
-ebcdic          -mouse           -startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
-emacs_tags      -mouse_dec       -statusline      -xterm_save
-eval            -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
-ex_extra        -mouse_jsbterm   -syntax
-extra_search    -mouse_netterm   -tag_binary

$ /usr/bin/vim --version|grep mouse
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For those features that are listed in `:version` output, you can use `if has('mouse')` conditionals.
- Another built-in function that can be used for many tests is [`:help exists()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#exists%28%29).
- The sledgehammer method: just prepend `:silent!` in front of the command; it will silence any errors.
- If vi is a different binary, you can also check the [`:help v:progpath`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Aprogpath) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting that in your ~/.vimrc:

```
set mouse=a
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

My `/usr/bin/vi` has mouse support:

```
#vi --version | grep mouse
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
```

But `vi` on my system is a symlink to `vim` so it's not applicable.

So you answered your question, your version of `vi` will not support mouse.

Comment: The problem is the `vi` has no feature of `mouse`

Comment: Ok makes sense good to know.

Comment: I found I can use `has('mouse')` to solve the setting, but I don't know how to check the colorscheme